# JQuery UI + tabs : How to kow to get the selected tab with imbricated tabs

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

I'm new to Jquery.
I'm using JQuery UI and i have imbricated Tabs : Tabs in tabs.

 ___________
 tab 1 | tab 2 | tab 3 | tab 4| tab 5 
   _____________
   tab 1-1 | tab 1-2 | tab 1-3 | tab 1-4| tab 1-5

I'm using $('#div').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {

selectedTab = ui.index;
 alert('selectedTab : ' + selectedTab);
});

to kown the selected index. 
If i click on "tab "1 the selected index returned is correct.

But when click on tabs in the second level ("tab 1-xx") the event is fired too. I want to resctriced the bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) on the first level of tab (tab x).

How can i do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the code of the tabs?

I supose the problem is because inside the "#div" you have defined the children.
So jquery trigger the event of tag select of tab 1-x to its parent

maybe you could try to unbind the event for each of the children.