# How to get even on tab selection, and get the currently instead of previously selected tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I'm using this snippet to bind on select event:

```
$("#myTabControl").tabs({
  select: function(event, ui){
    var selectedTabName = $("#myTabControl").find(".ui-tabs-selected").find("span").text();
    // Do stuff with the selected tab name.
  }
  ...
});
```

The problem is ... I'm getting the name of the tab that was previously selected, not the one that is currently being selected.

Any advice on how to get the latter?

Note - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355192/jquery-ui-tabs-how-to-kow-to-get-the-selected-tab-with-imbricated-tabs) is either very similar or a dup ... but I'm not sure it is phrased well enough (I'm not even sure if it's a complete dup or not).

Comment: Where does the value of `paneSelector` come from? Can we have some HTML to go along with this? A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be fantastic.

Comment: What does a console.log(event) and console.log(ui) return ? I think you binded to an event while the selection is made, and not after it's completed.

Comment: As for the possible duplicate - well, maybe. But it's not an exact duplicate, it's awfully worded and doesn't have any useful (or accepted) answers - even if they are duplicates, this question is potentially going to be much more useful for others in the future.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - changed `paneSelector` to `"#myTabControl"`. I assumed this was a default behavior. I'll try to come up with a `sscce` when I get a chance.

Comment: Take a look at @Didier's answer, he provided a working sscce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [select event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-select) is fired when you click on a tab button. At that moment, the tab has not yet changed.

You should use the [show event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-show):

```
$(paneSelector).tabs({
    show: function(e, ui) {
        var selectedTabName = $(paneSelector).find(".ui-tabs-selected span").text();
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/p36kp/)**

Comment: Duh, I should have made an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @FMaz008 - to the victor goes the spoils.